# Project runing But database connection not fount

Tags: database, laravel, database-connection

```
This is my .env file....
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

this is from database.php file

 'connections' => [


        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

but my project working there is no database connection.
where from database connecting???
and issue is when i upload it on live i getting error
"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"
i have cleared all cache and every thing but i didn't find database connection detail any where.
this project installed that time i give all details.

i have used all these
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan config:cache

php artisan route:clear

php artisan route:cache

but not working

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: Have you tried? Enter db name username and password on .env file?

Comment: yes i have entered username and password but .env file not affecting my project. if i remove database name or username project working fine but when i upload my project on live it's not working

Comment: when install this project i added a username and database that username and database name is working i don't know where from i can change these credentials because the .env file not supporting for change these credentials.

Comment: can we place .env file in vendor folder or have idea .env file anywhere in the project??or how .env files in the project

Answer (score 0):

Add your database details
username and password of your database in your env file

Comment: i have added username and database name in .env file but not working.

Comment: .env not supporting

Comment: there is no error on local machine but when i upload on live showing me database error i have change .env file as well config file but nothing happing

Comment: @KhalidZaibi make sure you have a .env file on your server as well as the database with the same name